# If $(T_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a flow on a submanifold $\Omega$ with boundary with velocity $v$ satisfying $\langle v,\nu_{∂Ω}\rangle=0$, then $T_t(∂Ω)⊆∂Ω$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, tangent-spaces

Let

- $\tau>0$;
- $d\in\mathbb N$;
- $v:[0,\tau]\times\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ be Lipschitz continuous in the second argument uniformly with respect to the first with $v(\;\cdot\;,x)\in C^0([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d)$;
- $X^x$ denote the unique element of $C^0([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d)$ with $$X^x(t)=x+\int_0^tv(s,X^x(s))\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau]\tag1$$ for $x\in\mathbb R^d$ and $$T_t(x):=X^x(t)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R^d$$ for $t\in[0,\tau]$.

> Let $\Omega$ be a $d$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold with boundary and $\nu_{\partial\Omega}$ denote the unique outer unit normal field on $\partial\Omega$. How can we show that, if $$\langle\left.v\right|_{[0,\:\tau]\times\partial\Omega},\nu_{\partial\Omega}\rangle=0\tag2,$$ then $$T_t(x)\in\partial\Omega\tag3$$ for all $x\in\partial\Omega$?

If necessary, assume that $v$ does not depend on the first argument.

I don't know if it'S relevant, but $\partial\Omega$ is a $(d-1)$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ (without boundary) and hence, for all $x\in\partial\Omega$, $$\mathbb R^d=T_x\:\partial\Omega\oplus N_x\:\partial\Omega\tag4$$ and $$N_x\:\partial\Omega=\mathbb R\nu_{\partial\Omega}(x)\tag5.$$ Moreover, it's trivially to see that $$v(0,x)\in T_x\:\partial\Omega\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\partial\Omega\tag6.$$

I have no idea how we can show the claim, but I was able to prove the following, possibly related, results:

**Proposition 1**: If $x\in\mathbb R^d$ with $$v(t,x)=0\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau]\tag7,$$ then $$T_t(x)=x\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau]\tag8.$$

**Proposition 2**: If $B\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ with $\left.v\right|_{[0,\:\tau]\times B}=0$, then $$\left.T_t\right|_B=\operatorname{id}_B\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau]\tag9.$$

**Proposition 3**: If $B\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ is open or closed and $\left.v\right|_{[0,\:\tau]\times\partial B}=0$, then $$T_t(B)=B\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau]\tag{10}.$$

### EDIT:

$T_t$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism on $\mathbb R^d$ and hence $$\partial T_t(\Omega)=T_t(\partial\Omega)\tag{11}$$ and $$\nu_{\partial T_t(\Omega)}(T_t(x))=\frac{\left({\rm D}T_t(x)^{-1}\right)^\ast\nu_{\partial\Omega}(x)}{\left\|\left({\rm D}T_t(x)^{-1}\right)^\ast\nu_{\partial\Omega}(x)\right\|}\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\partial\Omega\tag{12}$$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$. Does this help?

### EDIT 2:

$\Omega$ being a $d$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold with boundary means that each point of $\Omega$ is locally $C^1$-diffeomorphic to $\mathbb H^d:=\mathbb R^{d-1}\times[0,\infty)$ which in turn means that for each $p\in\Omega$, there is an open neighborhood $U$ (open in $\Omega$) of $x$ and a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $U$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb H^d$. A $C^1$-diffeomorphism between non-open subsets is a homeomorphism such that the function itself and its inverse are locally extendable to $C^1$-differentiable functions.

This particularly implies that $\partial\Omega$ is a $(d-1)$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: You can restrict your vector fields on $\partial \Omega$. It is still a continuous (indeed Lipschitz) vector fields, so there is a solution in $\partial \Omega$. By uniqueness, this solution has to be the one in $\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: @ArcticChar I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. By Proposition 1, it is clear to me that, if $\left.v\right|_{[0,\:\tau]\times\partial\Omega}=0$, then $\left.T_t\right|_{\partial\Omega}=\operatorname{id}_{\partial\Omega}$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$. But how is this related to $(2)$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Do we need to use that $\forall x,v\in\mathbb R^d:v\in T_x\:\partial\Omega\Leftrightarrow\langle v,\nu_{\partial\Omega}(x)\rangle=0$?

Comment: We definitely need to use that. Indeed this is more or less the definition of a normal vector. So $v(t, x) $ is tangential to $\partial \Omega$ for all $(t, x)$, then one can treat $v$ as a time dependent vector fields on $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: @ArcticChar I'm sure it's simple, but I don't get why this implies that we can treat $v$ as a time-dependent vector filed on $\partial\Omega$ (and I guess the precise meaning of that is that $\left.v\right|_{[0,\:\tau]\times\partial\Omega}$ mapsto $\partial\Omega$).

Comment: @ArcticChar Okay, we need to show that, if $x\in\partial\Omega$, then $T_t(x)$ maps into the manifold boundary $\partial\Omega$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$. I guess the simple, but crucial, observation is that if $\phi$ is a $C^\alpha$-diffeomorphism from a subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb R^d$ onto an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb H^k:=\mathbb R^{k-1}\times[0,\infty)$ and $T$ is a $C^\alpha$-diffeomorphism on $\mathbb R^d$, then $\phi':=\left.\phi\circ T^{-1}\right|_{\Omega'}$ is a $C^\alpha$-diffeomorphism from $\Omega':=T(\Omega)$ onto $U$.

Comment: @ArcticChar In the context of the question, $T_t$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism on $\mathbb R^d$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$ and hence the former observation implies that the image of a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold with boundary under $T_t$ is again a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold with boundary, for all $t\in[0,\tau]$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @ArcticChar This question drives me nuts! Meanwhile it seems to me that $(2)$ is not an additional assumption at all! It should always hold and hence I don't see why we should be able to infer $(3)$ from it. I've asked for a sufficient condition here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/370403/91890. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in \partial \Omega$, we want to show that $T_t(x) \in \partial \Omega$.

Since $\partial\Omega$ is a $C^1$ embedded submanifold in $\mathbb R^n$, there is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism $\varphi : U \to \varphi(U) \subset \mathbb R^n$, where $x\in U$, so that
\begin{align}
\tag{i}\varphi(x) &= (0,0,\cdots, 0),\\
\varphi (U\cap \partial \Omega) &= \varphi  (U) \cap \{ y\in \mathbb R^n: y_n = 0\}. 
\end{align}

Let $w(t, y)$ be the time dependent vector field on $\varphi (U)$ given by
$$\tag{ii} w(t, y) = (\phi_*)_q v(t, q),\ \ \text{ where } \varphi (q) = y.$$

Note that since $\varphi$ is $C^1$ and $v$ is continuous, $w$ is a time dependent $C^0$-vector field on $\varphi (U)$.

Since $\partial \Omega\cap U$ is sent to the plane $\{ y_n = 0\}$, we have
$$\tag{iii} y = (y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_{n-1}, 0)$$
whenever $\varphi (p) = y$ for some $p\in \partial \Omega \cap U$. Since $v$ is tangential to $\partial \Omega$ by (2), we have
$$\tag{iv} w(t, y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_{n-1}, 0)_n = 0,$$
where
$$w(t, y) = (w(t, y)_1, \cdots w(t, y)_n).$$
(To see this, for each point $y = (y_1, \cdots, y_{n-1}, 0)\in \varphi (U)$ and vector $V = (V_1, \cdots, V_{n-1}, 0)$, consider the curve $e(t) = y+tV$. We assume that $|t|$ is small so that $e(t) \in \varphi (U)$. By definition, $e(t) \in \varphi (U) \cap \{ y_n = 0\}$. By (i), $\varphi^{-1} \circ e$ is a curve on $\partial \Omega$. In particular,
$$ \varphi^{-1}_* v = \frac{d}{dt} \bigg|_{t=0} \varphi^{-1} (e(t)) \in T_{\varphi^{-1}(y)} \partial \Omega.$$
Since $V$ is arbitrary,
$$ (\varphi^{-1}_y)_* \{ V \in \mathbb R^n : V_n = 0\}\subset T_{\varphi^{-1}(y)}(\partial \Omega).$$
Since $\varphi^{-1}$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism, $\varphi^{-1}_*$ is injective. Since $\{V \in \mathbb R^n : V_n = 0\}$ is $n-1$-dimensional, we conclude that
$$ (\varphi^{-1}_y)_* \{ V \in \mathbb R^n : V_n = 0\}= T_{\varphi^{-1}(y)}(\partial \Omega), $$
or
$$\{ V \in \mathbb R^n : V_n = 0\}= \varphi_* T_{x}(\partial \Omega).$$
Now by (2) we have $v(z)\in T_z (\partial \Omega)$ for all $z \in \partial \Omega$. In particular,
$$ w = \varphi_* v(t, \cdot) \in \{V : V_n=0\},$$
which is (iv)).

Now consider the following system of first order differential equations
\begin{align}
y_1' &= w_1(t, y_1(t), y_2(t), \cdots, y_{n-1}(t), 0)_1,\\
\vdots \ \ &= \qquad \qquad\vdots \\
y_{n-1}' &= w_1(t, y_1(t), y_2(t), \cdots, y_{n-1}(t), 0)_{n-1}. 
\end{align}
with the initial conditions
$$ y_1(0) = 0, \cdots,  y_{n-1}(0) = 0.$$
Since $w$ is continuous, the existence theorem of ODE (see section I.1 in Hale's [ODEs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486472116), which is attributed to Peano) imples that the IVP solvable for some $t\in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$. Let
$$\tilde y(t) = (\tilde y_1(t), \tilde y_2(t), \cdots, \tilde y_{n-1}(t))$$
be a solution. Let
$$\tag{v}\gamma(t) = (\tilde y(t), 0).$$
Then $\gamma $ is a curve in $\varphi (U)$ and
\begin{align}
 \gamma(0) &=(\tilde y_1(0), \tilde y_2(0), \cdots, \tilde y_{n-1}(0), 0) \\
&= (0,0,\cdots, 0, 0) = \varphi(x).
\end{align}
Also,
\begin{align}
\gamma'(t) &= (\tilde y'_1(t), \tilde y'_2(t), \cdots, \tilde y'_{n-1}(t), 0)\\
&= \big( w(t, \tilde y(t), 0)_1 , w(t,\tilde y(t),0)_2, \cdots, w(t, \tilde y(t), 0)_{n-1}, 0\big) \\
&=\big( w(t, \gamma(t))_1 , w(t,\gamma(t) )_2, \cdots, w(t, \gamma(t))_{n-1}, w(t, \gamma(t))_n\big), 
\end{align}
where we used the definition of $\gamma(t)$ (v) and (iv). That is, $\gamma(t)$ solves the IVP
\begin{align} 
\gamma' &=  w(t, \gamma), \\
\gamma(0) &= \varphi (x).
\end{align}
Let
$$\tag{vi} \eta(t) = \varphi^{-1} \circ \gamma(t).$$
Then $ \eta (0) = \varphi^{-1} \varphi (x) = x$ and
\begin{align} 
\eta'(t) &= (\varphi^{-1}_*)_{\gamma(t)} \gamma'(t) \\
&=  (\varphi^{-1}_*)_{\varphi (\eta(t))} w(t, \gamma(t)) \\
&=  (\varphi^{-1}_*)_{\varphi (\eta(t))}  (\varphi_*)_{\eta(t)} v(t, \eta(t)) \\
&= v(t, \eta(t))
\end{align}
by (vi) and (ii). Thus $\eta(t)$ is a solution to the IVP
\begin{align}
\eta' &= v(t, \eta), \\
\eta(0) &= x.
\end{align}
Since $v$ satisfies the assumption for the uniqueness theorem, we find that $\eta(t)$ is the solution: Thus $\eta(t) = T_t(x)$. Since $\gamma (t)_n = 0$ by (v), we have $\eta (t) \in \partial \Omega$ by (vi). Thus
$$ T_t(x) \in \partial \Omega.$$
Since $x\in \partial \Omega$ is arbitrary, we conclude
$$ T_t(\partial \Omega) \subset \partial \Omega.$$

**Edit:** Up to now we have just proved that for all $x\in \partial \Omega$, there is $\epsilon>0$ depending on $x, \partial \Omega$ so that $T_t(x) \in \partial \Omega$ for all $|t| <\epsilon$. This is not exactly the same as $$ T_t(\partial \Omega) \subset \partial \Omega,  \ \ \text{ for all } t \in [0, \tau]. $$

To show this we merely need to use the closedness of $\partial \Omega$ as a subset in $\mathbb R^n$: indeed, for each $x$, let

$$ \chi_x = \sup A, $$
where
$$A = \{ \nu>0: T_t(x) \in \partial \Omega \ \ \text{ for all } |t|<\nu \}.$$
Note that the supremum exists since above set is nonempty. Now we show that $\chi_x = \tau$. If not, then $\chi_x<\tau$.
First of all, the Lipschitz continuity of $v$ implies that $T_t$ is defined for all $t\in [0,\tau]$. By definition of $\chi_x$,
$$ T_t(x) \in \partial \Omega, \ \ \ \text{ for all }t<\chi_x.$$
Since $\partial \Omega$ is closed, we conclude that $ T_{\chi_x}(x)\in \partial \Omega$. Then the IVP
$$\begin{cases} x'= v(t, x), \\
x(\chi_x) = T_{\chi_x}(x)
\end{cases}$$
is (uniquely) solvable for some $t \in (\chi_x - \delta, \chi_x + \delta)$. In particular, By the same argument we did, we have
$$T_t(x) \in \partial \Omega$$
whenever $t < \chi_x + \delta'$ for some $\delta' < \delta$. But this contradicts to the definition of $\chi_x$. Thus we must have $\chi_x = \tau$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think there are some issues in your post: (a) $\Omega$ does *not* need to be open. For example, $\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb R^d:\left\|x\right\|\le1\}$ is a valid choice. (The open subsets of $\mathbb R^d$ are precisely the $d$-dimensional embedded $C^\infty$-submanifolds of $\mathbb R^d$.)

Comment: (b) The chart $\varphi$ around $x$ you are considering should be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism onto an open subset of $\mathbb H^d:=\mathbb R^{d-1}\times[0,\infty)$ with $\varphi(x)\in\partial\mathbb H^d=\mathbb R^{d-1}\times\{0\}$. You're even assuming that $\varphi(x)=0$. Could you say why this is possible? (Is it necessary for the rest of your proof?)

Comment: Oh, and what are you denoting by $\phi_*$ and $(\phi_*)_q$?

Comment: (c) I don't get how you obtain (iv) and please note that you've confused $d$ and $n$.

Comment: Please add your definition of $C^1$ embedded submanifold with boundary into your post. To me it just mean that that the boundary is an $C^1$ embedded submanifold. $\varphi_*$ is the jacobian matrix. And yes I use n insread of d in my answer. @0xbadf00d

Comment: I've added the definition to the end of my question. You say that $\varphi_\ast$ is the Jacobian matrix, but shouldn't it be the [pushforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)) instead? The domain of a chart $\phi$ is an open subset $U$ of the submanifold with boundary $M$ and hence is not open in $\mathbb R^d$. So, the usual notion of derivative is not applicable.

Comment: If you know the term pushforward, then yes it is the pushforward. In the answer I used only that $\partial \Omega$ is a $C^1$-embedded submanifold in $\mathbb R^n$ @0xbadf00d (I have made a small edit).

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not clear to me how you obtained (iv).

Comment: I guess the main idea is to take $x\in\partial M$, $y:=\phi(x)$ and consider a flow $Y\in C^1([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d)$ with $Y(0)=y$ and some velocity $w$. This flow should "locally" be $Y(t):=\phi(X^x(t))$ for $t\in[0,\delta]$ and some $\delta\in(0,\tau]$. Intuitively it's clear to me that as long as $\delta$ is "sufficiently small", $X^x(t)\in U$ for all $t\in[0,\delta]$ so that $Y$ is well-defined. And if we knew this, it's clear to me that $w$ should be equal to the $w$ you've defined in your answer.

Comment: However, I don't know how to prove $X^x(t)\in U$ for the same reason I don't know how to prove the claim in the question. And I really have no idea how you came up with (iv).

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you reply. Meanwhile I've figured out more things which I don't understand, for example, how do you know that the ODE $y'(t)=w(t,y(t))$ as a (unique) solution? If I'm not missing something, $w$ will not be Lipschitz continuous in the second argument uniformly with respect to the first - even though $v$ has this property - and hence you cannot conclude the existence/uniqueness by the contraction mapping theorem as usual. But the more crucial problem is that $w$, as given by (ii), is not well-defined, if I'm not missing something.

Comment: In order for the pushforward to be well-defined, you need $v(t,q)\in T_q\:\partial\Omega$. This is only ensured for $q\in\varphi(U\cap\partial\Omega)$, but you've defined it for all $q\in\varphi(U)$. And last, but not least, I think we need to define $w(t,q)$ for $q$ belonging to a *closed* subset. Maybe I'm missing something! And so I would really appreciate if you could reply to these issues. (Please take note of my related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3809204/47771.)

Comment: @0xbadf00d I have added something about (iv). Concerning the uniqueness, I did not use uniqueness at $y' = w(t, y)$. I used existence only (which we have since $w$ is continuous). I used only uniqueness for the problem $\eta' = v(t, \eta)$ later. I have also added something to address the issue raised by Jack Lee in the MO post concerning the properness. There is a question mark (?) which I cannot justify yet since it is not clear to me what uniform means in the definition of $v$ (please clarify).

Comment: Uniform means that $v$, considered as a mapping $E\to C^0([0,\tau],E)$ given by x\mapsto(t\mapsto v(t,x))$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the claim that continuity of $w$ is sufficient to ensure the existence? And could you shortly say why $w$ is well-defined at all? I still think you need to restrict to $q\in\varphi(U\cap\partial\Omega)$ since the pushforward isn't defined otherwise.

Comment: I think the most crucial part of your proof lies in the existence of a solution your ODE $y'(t)=w(t,y(t))$ and the most relevant part of it is that $y(t)\in\varphi(U\cap\partial\Omega)$.

Comment: I have added the reference of the existence in the answer. @0xbadf00d Concerning the definition of $v$, does that means $$ \sup_t \| v(t, x) - v(t, y)\|\le C\| x-y\|?$$ Putting $x=y$ that seems to force $v$ to be time independent....

Comment: And your question about $\varphi$: no it is defined as a $C^1$-diffeomorphism between $U$, $\varphi(U)$, both open sets in $\mathbb R^n$. So $\varphi_*$ is defined everywhere in $U$.

Comment: (a) No it does mean $$\sup_{t\in[0,\:\tau]}\left\|v(t,x)-v(t,y)\right\|\le c_1\left\|x-y\right\|\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in\mathbb R^d$$ for some $c_1\ge0$. (b) Maybe I'm missing something, but to me it seems like your mixing up the definition of charts for $\Omega$ and $\partial\Omega$. A chart for $\partial\Omega$ around $x\in\partial\Omega$ is a diffeomorphism $\varphi_1$ of an open subset $U_1$ of $\partial\Omega$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: On the other hand, a chart for $\Omega$ around $x\in\partial\Omega$ is a diffeomorphism $\varphi_2$ of an open subset $U_2$ of $\Omega$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb H^d$ with $\varphi_2(x)\in\partial\mathbb H^k$. And if $\pi$ is the projection of $\mathbb R^d$ onto $\mathbb R^{d-1}$ with $\pi(\partial\mathbb H^d)=\mathbb R^{d-1}$, then the restriction of $\pi\circ\varphi_2$ to $U_2\cap\partial\Omega$ is a chart for $\partial\Omega$ around $x$ (i.e. a possible choice for $(U_1,\varphi_1)$). Which one are you using?

Comment: Forget about $\Omega$: I am only using that $\partial \Omega$ is an embedded submanifold of dimension $n-1$ in $\mathbb R^n$. The existence of $U$ for each $x\in \partial \Omega$ is the definition of an embedded submanifold (this is stated in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold#Embedded_submanifolds), is the definition I found in Hirsch's differential topology, and probably you can find it in Lee (I do not have the book now). @0xbadf00d

Comment: If you're only using that $\partial\Omega$ is a submanifold, then you're using the definition I gave with $(U_1,\varphi_1)$, but then I don't get why you take the intersection with $\partial\Omega$ in $$\varphi (U\cap \partial \Omega) = \varphi  (U) \cap \{ y\in \mathbb R^n: y_n = 0\}.$$ That's what's confusing me, since this seems to indicate you're using $\varphi$ as a chart for $\Omega$ (i.e. a chart of the kind $(U_2,\varphi_2)$)

Comment: I am using exactly this one (in wiki): "There is an intrinsic definition of an embedded submanifold which is often useful. Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold, and let $k$ be an integer such that $0\le k \le n$. A $k$-dimensional embedded submanifold of $M$ is a subset $S \subset M$ such that for every point $p\in S$ there exists a chart ($U \subset M, \varphi : U\to \mathbb R^n$) containing $p$ such that $\varphi(S\cap U)$ is the intersection of a $k$-dimensional plane with $\varphi (U)$".

Comment: where in our case, $M = \mathbb R^n$, $k=n-1$, $S = \partial \Omega$ @0xbadf00d

Comment: I'm not familiar with this definition. Mine is that a $k$-dimensional $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ is locally $C^1$-diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^k$ and a $k$-dimensional $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary is locally $C^1$-diffeomorphic to $\mathbb H^k$. That's the same definition Lee is using. I'm not sure if both definitions are equivalent or how we can construct a chart in your sense from a chart in my sense.

Comment: Well I dunno how to convince you that the definition that I am using is standard. The definition that you gave looks more like the definition of manifold (in 1.) or manifold with boundary (in 2.). I will check Lee's book later (if I somehow find a softcopy). @0xbadf00d

Comment: In an online version of Lee's book, the one I stated is the definition stated in the book (at p.97 in the online version, in chapter 5 "submanifolds"). The same definition is also used in Tu's [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441973993), definition 9.1 @0xbadf00d

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I can fix my main problem with (ii) even with my definition. However, I've taken a look at your reference for the Peano existence theorem. It requires the velocity to be defined on an open subset of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^{d-1}$. Since we need existence for the initial value problem at time $t=0$, it seems like we would need $v$ to be defined for times in $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. But our $v$ is only defined for nonnegative times. Can we fix this issue by extending $v$ in some way?

Comment: Please take a look at [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3813950/47771). How do we prove the equality in $(21)$? You didn't approach this point in your answer.

Comment: Sorry for replying to this post again, but I just observed that it's not clear to me how you conclude that $w$ is continuous. Wouldn't we need $(\phi_*)_q$ to depend continuously on $q$ for that? How is this possible? $(\phi_*)_q$ is a map defined on $T_q\:\partial\Omega$; so it's domain even depends on $q$. Please take a look at the question I've asked for that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3834959/47771.

Answer (score 1):

[Arctic Char's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3807568/47771) is perfectly fine and helped me a lot to understand the main idea. However, at least for my own reference, I post an additional answer which uses definitions of the involved concepts which I'm more familiar with.

I will slightly deviate from the notation used in the question. First of all, let $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$ and $M$ be a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary.

We show first that, for every chart $(\Omega,\phi)$ of $M$ and $x\in\partial M$, there is a $\varepsilon>0$ with $$T_t(x)\in\partial\Omega\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\varepsilon)\tag{13}.$$ In order to do so, let $\pi$ denote the canonical projection of $\mathbb R^k$ onto $\mathbb R^{k-1}$ with $\pi(\partial\mathbb H^k)=\mathbb R^{k-1}$ and $$\tilde\phi:=\pi\circ\left.\phi\right|_{\partial\Omega}.$$ Note that $$\tilde U:=\tilde\phi(\partial\Omega)$$ is $\mathbb R^{k-1}$-open and let $$h(t,\tilde u):=T_{\tilde\phi^{-1}(\tilde u)}(\tilde\phi)v\left(t,\tilde\phi^{-1}(\tilde u)\right)\;\;\;\text{for }(t,u)\in[0,\tau]\times\tilde U.$$ Remember that $$T_{\tilde\phi^{-1}(\tilde u)}(\tilde\phi)^{-1}={\rm D}\tilde\phi^{-1}(\tilde u)={\rm D}\phi^{-1}(\iota(\tilde u))\iota=T_{\tilde\phi^{-1}(\tilde u)}(\phi)^{-1}\circ\iota\tag{14}$$ for all $\tilde u\in\tilde U$, where $\iota$ denotes the canonical embedding of $\mathbb R^{k-1}$ into $\mathbb R^k$ with $\iota\mathbb R^{k-1}=\partial\mathbb H^k$. Now let $\tilde u:=\tilde\phi(x)$. By the Peano existence theorem, there is a $\varepsilon>0,Y\in C^1([0,\varepsilon),\tilde U)$ with $$Y(t)=\tilde u+\int_0^th(s,Y(s))\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\varepsilon)\tag{15}.$$ Let $$Z:=\tilde\phi^{-1}\circ Y.$$ By $(14)$, $$T_{Z(t)}(\tilde\phi)^{-1}={\rm D}\tilde\phi^{-1}(Y(t))\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\varepsilon)\tag{16}$$ and hence $$Z'(t)={\rm D}\tilde\phi^{-1}(Y(t))Y'(t)=\underbrace{T_{Z(t)}(\tilde\phi)^{-1}T_{Z(t)}(\tilde\phi)}_{=\:\operatorname{id}_{T_x\:\partial\Omega}}v(t,Z(t))=v(t,Z(t))\tag{17}$$ for all $t\in[0,\varepsilon)$ by the chain rule. Moreover, by definition, $Z(0)=x$ and hence, by uniqueness, $$\left.X^x\right|_{[0,\:\varepsilon)}=Z\tag{18}.$$ Clearly, $$Z([0,\varepsilon))\subseteq\tilde\phi^{-1}(\tilde U)=\partial\Omega.\tag{19}.$$

From this result, we have obtained that $$\forall x\in\partial M:\exists\varepsilon>0:\forall t\in[0,\varepsilon):T_t^{(v)}(x)\in\partial M.\tag{20}.$$ And if $\partial M$ is $\mathbb R^d$-closed$^1$, we can show (as Arctic Char did) that $$T_t(\partial M)\subseteq\partial M\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau].\tag{21}$$

> However, how do we conclude that $(21)$ is actually an equality?

---

$^1$ This is, for example, the case when $M$ is a $d$-dimensional properly embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary, since then $M$ is $\mathbb R^d$-closed and $\partial M$ coincides with the topological boundary of $M$.