# If $ϕ$ is a boundary chart of a $k$-dimensional submanifold $M$ with boundary, then $(T_xϕ)v\in\mathbb R^{k-1}×\{0\}$ for all $v\in T_x\:\partial M$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary, tangent-spaces, submanifold, pushforward

Let $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$ and $M$ be a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary, $(\Omega,\phi)$ be a $k$-dimensional $C^1$-chart$^1$ of $M$ and $$U:=\phi(\Omega\cap\partial M)=\phi(\Omega)\cap\partial\mathbb H^k\tag1.$$

Let $x\in\Omega\cap\partial M$, $v\in T_x\:\partial M$ and $^2$ $$w:=(T_x\phi)v.$$ Can we show that $w_k=0$?

Maybe it's obvious, but I guess it follows by a suitable characterization of $T_{\phi(x)}\:\partial\mathbb H^k$. The desired claim seems to be used in equation (iv) of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3807568/47771) and I absolutely don't get why it holds.

---

$^1$ i.e. $\Omega$ is an open subset of $M$ and $\phi$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism of $\Omega$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb H^k:=\mathbb R^{k-1}\times[0,\infty)$.

$^2$ If $M_i$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb R^{d_i}$ with boundary and $f:M_1\to M_2$ is $C^1$-differentiable at $x\in M_1$, let $$T_xf:T_x\:M_1\to T_{f(x)}\:M_2$$ denote the [pushforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)).

Comment: Choose a curve $\alpha$ representing $v$ such that $\alpha(0) = x, \dot{\alpha}(0) = w$ and $\alpha(t) \in \partial M \cap \Omega$ for all relevant $t$. Set $\tilde{\alpha}(t) = (\phi \circ \alpha)(t) = (\alpha_1(t), \dots, \alpha_k(t))$. Assume that $w_k = \dot{\alpha}_k(0) > 0$. Then $\alpha_k$ is increasing near $t = 0$ and so for $t > 0$ small enough we must have $\alpha_k(t) > 0$ (as $\alpha_k(0) = 0$) but then $\alpha(t)$ is an interior point of $M$ for small enough and positive $t$ contradicting the fact that $\alpha(t) \in \partial M$. The case $w_k < 0$ is similar.

Comment: @levap Thank you for your comment. I think the picture is a bit clearer now, but I still don't get why we can choose things accordingly. I've tried to phrase my problems more precisely in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3809498/47771). Please take a look. (I'll delete *this* question soon.)